# Using $sceProvider functionality from $sce

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

From Angular documents it says that `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist` can set the trusted resource URLs, But I need that functionality from the controller.

I want to set a whitelist of trusted resource URLs within my service. Therefore, I am only allowed to use `$sce` service and not provider..

I was trying to implement this example and it caused me an error (
"$sce:unsafe
Require a safe/trusted value"):

`` this.renderUrl = this.$sce.getTrustedUrl(${this.baseUrl}) + `/x/y/?name=${this.name}; ``

Then inject the the `renderUrl` into the html:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{$ctrl.renderUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to set a trusted resource URLs from `$sce` service, so it will be added to the whitlist of trusted resource URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Filter :

```
app.filter('trusturl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
}]);
```

In your service:

```
// Injecting Filter in Service
app.service('trustUrlService', function ($scope,$filter) {

  $scope.trustUrl = function(url){
    return $filter('trusturl')(url);
  };

});
```

In Controller use like this:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,trustUrlService) {  
  $scope.url = trustUrlService.trustUrl(url);
});
```

In Template you could use like this:

```
<iframe ng-src={{ imageHref | trusturl }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks I am aware of that option. I am looking for a way it will be much more generic in case I will have the same prefix of base url.  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://example.com/url'); limits me and force me to call that method each time for the same base url.

Comment: @Moris Updated my answer

Comment: is there any specifice requirement to use it from the service?